# Javascript fail (this.* misdirected), ?why

Tags: javascript, oop, conceptual

When creating a pointer to a function inside an object
"this" is not correctly resolved
Try this example to get the concept...

```
// this.* fail
a = { x : 123,  f : function(){ console.log( this.x ) } }
a.f()     // 123
b = a.f   // b points to a.f now
b()       // should print 123 but gaves 'undefined'
```

- of course we could force the resolution using the object name instead of "this"
  but then we loose funcionality...

Comment: Fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/a6weL8f3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `bind`:

```
b = a.f.bind(a);
b(); // 123
```

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

> The bind() method creates a new function that, when called,
>   has its this keyword set to the provided value, with a given sequence
>   of arguments preceding any provided when the new function is called.

Answer (score 2):

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this.

> **Function context**
>
> Inside a function, the value of this depends on how the function is
>   called.
>
> **Simple call**
>
> ```
> function f1(){
>   return this;
> }
>
> f1() === window; // global object
> ```

This is what you are doing in the 2nd case `b()`. You are basically calling x on the global object. So

```
var x = 456;
// this.* fail
a = { x : 123,  f : function(){ console.log( this.x ) } }
a.f()     // 123
b = a.f   // b points to a.f now
b()       // prints 456
```

---

> **As an object method**
>
> When a function is called as a method of an object, its this is set to
>   the object the method is called on.
>
> In the following example, when o.f() is invoked, inside the function
>   this is bound to the o object.
>
> ```
> var o = {
>   prop: 37,
>   f: function() {
>     return this.prop;
>   }
> };
>
> console.log(o.f()); // logs 37
> ```

This is what happens in the first case.

Answer (score 1):

when you invoke a method on an instance, the context of the method is the instance (the `this` keyword in the `f` method is a reference to `a` when doing `a.f()`).

However, when you keep the reference to the function in a variable, when invoking it, you actually lose the context, so `this` becomes the global context (which is `window` in a browser).

So, you need to give the context to the function when you are invoking it thanks to `call` or `apply` methods:

[Function.prototype.call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)

[Function.prototype.apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)

Your code becomes:

```
b = a.f;
b.call(a); // or b.apply(a)
```

Comment: Or use `bind`. `this` depends entirely on how the function is called, it won't necessarily be the global context, either.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to assign this to some variable in an object:

```
var a = {
   x : 1,
   self : this,
   f : function() {
      self.x++;       
   },
   show : function() {
      alert(self.x);
   }
}

a.f();    
a.show();      

d = a.show;
d();
```